# How to parse a data class into JSON string for Kotlin?

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin, gson

I wonder what is the way to convert a `Kotlin` data class into its equivalent `json` string. Json `keys` should be configurable.

Let's say I have a class,

```
data class Student(name: String?, roll: Int?, mark: Int?) {

}
```

I want to make a Json from this `Student` object where keys will be,

`stundent_name, stundent_roll, stundent_mark`

Moreover, I may also need to make a json from list of student with key `students`. How can I do so? I know using `Gson` I can create object from json string. How to do the reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data class Student(
    @SerializedName("stundent_name")
    val name: String?,
    @SerializedName("stundent_roll")
    val roll: Int?,
    @SerializedName("stundent_mark")
    val mark: Int?
)
```

And the code for convertion is:

```
val gson = Gson()
val student = Student("John", 1, 5)
gson.toJson(student)
```

This code makes String like this:

```
{"stundent_mark":5,"stundent_name":"John","stundent_roll":1}
```

And if you need to create JsonArray, just do the same with your List of students:

```
gson.toJson(list)
```